# Unmatch raster and polygon data in R

Tags: r, raster

[image: Unmatch dem and shp file]

The polygons (read in from a shapefile) are :

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 653 
extent      : -7115213, 4895580, 1368240, 7805331  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=55 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-154 
+x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=clrk66 
+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat 
variables   : 6
names       : cat,   NAME,      AREA_MI,      lccount,        lcsum,      
lcmean 
min values  :   1, Alaska, 1.006402e+00, 1.000000e+01, 0.000000e+00,  
0.00000000 
max values  :  99, Alaska, 9.945810e-01, 9.900000e+01, 9.960000e+02, 
12.00000000
```

The raster (elevation) data is

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 6800, 9200, 62560000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1305.521, 946.6311  (x, y)
extent      : -7115213, 4895580, 1368240, 7805331  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=55 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-154 
+x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=clrk66 
+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat 
data source : /Users/hong/Documents/GitHub/Alaska/akshd300m.tif 
names       : akshd300m 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

Does anyone how to solve this? I use tmap to plot this figure

Answer (score 0):

Although the coordinate reference system is reported as `+proj=aea +lat_1=55 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-154 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=clrk66` for both data sets, clearly that cannot be true. It should be easy to figure out which one is correct by transforming known polygons to that crs. For example

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
usa <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=1)
ak <- usa[usa$NAME_1 == 'Alaska', ]
ak_asa <- spTransform(ak, '+proj=aea +lat_1=55 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=50 +lon_0=-154 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=clrk66')
```

And plotting that one as well. Having established which one is correct (hopefully one of the two is), you can then try to trace back what went wrong with the other one. With the information you have provided we cannot figure that out for you.